# Why innerText,innerHTML property doesnt work on input tags in javascript?

Tags: javascript, attributes, innertext

So i stumbled upon following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

Name: <input type="text" id="myText" value="Mickey">

<p>Click the button to change the value of the text field.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("myText").value = "Johnny Bravo";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And not having used .value before in javascripte i thought to substitute it by innerText property but it just simply doesnt work !

I am having an idea that maybe as `<input/>` is a self closing tag that's why innerText isnt able to insert in between it ? As such to insert in between an element there atleast should be 2 tags

SO can anyone consolidate this ? Or if not then why .innerText isnt working here instead of .value

Comment: Note that assigning an id to an element creates a [window property of the same name](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/window-object.html#named-access-on-the-window-object) in HTML5. Setting the `id` attribute of an existing element also creates a window property of the same name. (This is the correct answer to a deleted question you asked and answered previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3434278/5217142).)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `inner` refers to the content that is "in between" the opening and closing tags of an element. For example:

```
<p>This is the "innerText" or "textContent"</p>
```

The `<input>` element doesn't have a closing tag, so it can never contain any "inner" content. For these elements, use the `.value` property to access their content.

There are other elements that do not have a closing tag, but in the following cases, the elements don't have `innerText` or `.value` because they are not designed to store any data, only to have a semantic or structural effect on the HTML:

- `<area>`
- `<base>`
- `<br>`
- `<col>`
- `<colgroup>` when the span is present
- `<command>`
- `<embed>`
- `<hr>`
- `<img>`
- `<input>`
- `<keygen>`
- `<link>`
- `<meta>`
- `<param>`
- `<source>`
- `<track>`
- `<wbr>`